# EventHandler returntype as constructor?

Tags: java

I have myself an @EventHandler which I'd like to work insync with a constructor.package

```
public class MonsterLevel implements Listener{

public MonsterLevel(int level, Player p) {
        switch (level) { //The onclick Event should Increment this level whenever it is activated.
             case 1: 
                 //Changes Here
                 return;

             case 2: 
                 //Changes Here
                 return;
             default: 
                      System.out.println("Level is too high");
                      return;
             }
    }

@EventHandler //When the player activates this event it should run the MonsterLevel Constructor Method.
public MonsterLevel LevelUp(PlayerInteractEvent event){ 
 MonsterLevel level1 = new MonsterLevel(1,p);
 MonsterLevel level2 = new MonsterLevel(2,p);
                if(level==1) {
                    level++;
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Level: " + level);
                    return level1;
                }
                if(level==2) {
                    level++;
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Level: " + level);
                    return level2;
                }return level4;
                }
        } else {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Failed to Level Up");
        }
    return null; // Goes to switch's default?
    }
}
```

I have commented my code above. But what I'm asking is, as a standard of Java, can I make the eventhandler utilise the constructor? If not, can someone signpost me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Could you create an SSCCE describing your question? I bet you can express your question without monsters and stuff.

Comment: Do you have an error message? I don't see Problems here on first sight.

Comment: @aioobe I have updated above code so that it's shorter, easier to understand

Comment: @Fildor I heard from a dev not too long ago that an EventHandler shouldn't return a constructor and I wanted to know if that was right or not.

Comment: Did he actually use those terms? "An EventHandler **shouldn't return a constructor** "? Personally, I'd have the EventHandler change the state of the object that it is called on. But I don't know your design ...

Comment: @Fildor That's exactly what he said. Although what you say could work. Thanks :) Given comment upvotes as respect :)

Comment: I am not sure what the question actually is. However, here are some thoughts: 1) You cannot return constructors in Java. Constructors create objects. You can of course (and as you do) return objects that were created. 2) Event Handlers are callback methods, usually those are used to inform an object about something and the caller rarely expects something in return. So what is it that your EventHandler should actually do?

Comment: Could you tell us more about the `@EventHandler`? or actually more to the point, is this bukkit question: (https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/can-an-eventhandler-method-return-type-be-a-constructor.305386/) yours? My answer would be: Don't return the constructed object or even use the constructor. Instead, place your level increment logic in the `LevelUp` method! check the http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference

Comment: @SirRichie My `@EventHandler` is meant to run the constructor method with the level being passed through when a specific event happens. In this case it's when a huge clicks on an object (`PlayerInteractEvent`).

I'm basically trying to make it so when a user Levelsup they then run methods from another class (which I put in the switch from the constructor).

Comment: Why do this in a constructor and not in a normal method?

Comment: Following the api reference ljgw linked, an eventhandler not only should not return an object but **must** be a void, I would say.